# Achartengine does not show value for single data

Tags: android, achartengine

I am researching about Achartengine for drawing simple line charts.
I got stuck on a single interesting thing.

I have already set:

```
renderer.setDisplayChartValues(true);
renderer.setChartValuesTextSize(30f);
```

However, it only shows the value when my data has two or more values.
I captured the screen for you to easily understand my point.

[image]
[image]

Does anyone know why?
Please help me.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Ihad the same issue. I solved it by editing the aChartEngine source code.

In particular, in:

**XYChart.java - drawChartValuesText()**

I changed this

```
protected void drawChartValuesText(Canvas canvas, XYSeries series, SimpleSeriesRenderer renderer,
    Paint paint, List<Float> points, int seriesIndex, int startIndex)
{
    if (points.size() > 1) { // there are more than one point
```

to this

```
protected void drawChartValuesText(Canvas canvas, XYSeries series, SimpleSeriesRenderer renderer,
    Paint paint, List<Float> points, int seriesIndex, int startIndex)
{
    if (points.size() > 2) { // there are more than one point
```

So, 1 has to become **2**, and it magically works.
Credits and respects to `Matthieu Holz` for the precious hint

Comment: Thanks, Der Golem! Your answer saved my life :D